# How to create a word press user with hashedpassword

Tags: plugins, login, password

I have set of user data from another wordpress site and i want o create users for each of them  in  a another wordpress web site..,it is works fine with `wp_insert_user($user)` but problem is the password is hashed agin..,so i can't log with that login information,so how can i create user with hash password or stop creating hashed password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to update the password column in the database (see below). But this alone won't work. Password hashes are salted using the SALT keys in your `wp-config.php` (this must be kept secret). Your new site would **need to have identical keys** for the password verification to work.

The following function updates a given user's password field (in the database) with the provided (hashed) password:

```
/**
 * @param int $user_id The user ID
 * @param string $hashed_password The hashed password
 * @return int The number of rows updated (should be 1 or 0 ).
*/
function wpse_update_password_field( $user_id, $hashed_password ){
   global $wpdb;

   return $wpdb->update( 
        $wpdb->users,
        array( 'user_pass' => $hashed_password ),
        array( 'ID' => $user_id )
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for creating hash passwords have a look at this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password

IT sounds like it's not hashing it properly. for example:

```
$password_hashed = '$P$B55D6LjfHDkINU5wF.v2BuuzO0/XPk/';
$plain_password = 'test';
```

That utilises MD5.

Try reading into **wp_hash_password**